# Show Custom field value instead of title in WP Menu

Tags: custom-field, menus, navigation

any idea how to display **custom field values** (I am using [acf](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/) for those) in a Wordpress Menu instead of the respective `wp_title`?

Have nothing to show, as I have nothing tried yet, as I haven't found anything that could help me. That's the reason for posting the question in here.

I'd be very thankful for your support, but please no ranting for not having a code.

Comment: Try [`wp_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_title/) and/or [`pre_get_document_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_document_title/) filters and come back then.

Comment: Sorry, wrong link to the `wp_title` hook. [Here is the right one](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_title/).